# Python ternary expression: "Is assigned to nothing"

Tags: python, asynchronous, discord.py

This is my code:

```py
@bot.command()
async def online(ctx):
    """Fetch all members and add to list based on status"""
    onlinemembers, offlinemembers = [], []
    # Loop over individual member in guild.members list
    for m in ctx.guild.members:
        # Add to list of online members if status is online or dnd, else add to offline list
        onlinemembers.append(str(m)) if str(m.status) in ['online', 'dnd'] else offlinemembers.append(str(m))
    await ctx.send(f"Online members: {', '.join(onlinemembers)}\nOffline members: {', '.join(offlinemembers)}")
```

It works just as intended.
Before using a ternary expression I did something like this:

```py
        ...
        if str(member.status) in ['online', 'dnd']:
            onlinemembers.append(str(member))
        else:
            offlinemembers.append(str(member))
        ...
```

Which also worked fine, but I wanted to write it shorter.

The top code gives me this error in the linter:
`Expression "onlinemembers.append(str(m)) if str(m.status) in ['online', 'dnd'] else offlinemembers.append(str(m))" is assigned to nothing`

How can I do something like this without such an error showing up?

Comment: That's right, the result of the conditional expression (always None) *isn't* assigned. You have an expression for its side effect, which is bad form. Why not e.g. `(onlinemembers if str(m.status) in ("online", "dnd") else offlinemembers).append(str(m))`?

Comment: Ahhh I see. I could've done something like `L = l1 if x else l2 L.append(y)` but your solution is a lot better. Thanks!